# Is there a supported implementation of Prolog which interfaces cleanly to Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, prolog, dcg

I have been very happy with some language translations I've done with Prolog, but long ago.  I'm now using Python for general purpose programming.  The area is DNA sequencing data processing, but that's besides the point.

I am interested in using a DCG (definite clause grammar) for translation into a target language. (A DCG is very close to being a set of Prolog predicates, and a DCG to Prolog interpretation layer is almost trivial, as I recall.) The method I used was to parse an input language, and at the same time as parsing the input expressions, build a network structure to represent a deeper model of the expression.  Another grammar then served to elaborate that model into a valid expression in the target language.

This time, though, I'm looking to do just the second half, to take an internal model (in a network of Python objects) and translate them into a target language.  (This target language is a workflow configuration language, incidentally, and the network of objects are those used by a pre-existing less general workflow engine that I hope to abandon.)

So, are there any modern, supported Prolog implementations that cleanly interface to Python?

Comment: Python interfaces cleanly to C, as do most modern Prolog implementations. But if you are not shifting a lot of data, it might be enough to use a standard data interchange format like JSON, or even SGML (if you're into this kind of stuff).

Comment: PS: SWI-Prolog at least has good libraries for both JSON and XML/SGML. I would be very surprised if the other more popular implementations don't have those too.

Answer (score 1):

YAP provides a Python interface package:

http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~vsc/yap/

If you want to try it, I suggest you start with use the current git version found at:

https://github.com/vscosta/yap-6.3

Some examples are provided with the distribution:

https://github.com/vscosta/yap-6.3/tree/master/packages/python/examples

Comment: There are a few other interfaces between Python and Prolog, such as [PySwip](https://github.com/yuce/pyswip) for SWI-Prolog.